# Capturing FTP connection error code from WinSCP environment in a batch script

Tags: ftp, winscp

There is a connection problem to a server as follows:

```
C:\Temp\ATS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
winscp> open ftp://root:root@10.1.0.119
Connecting to 10.1.0.119 ...
Connection failed.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection failed.
winscp>
```

I have to connect to 15 such servers and collect some traffic data. I should be able to flag the ones that give errors on trying to connect. How can I do that from a script. My batch script contains:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script=C:\Temp\ATS\get5024.txt
```

and the contents of get5024.txt is:

```
open ftp://root:root@10.1.0.119
bin 
cd /opt/logs
lcd C:\Temp\ATS\
get TRAF_*.dat
exit
```